# Case' contactId always changes back when I try to change it

Tags: apex, case

In our org in case object, when I tried to change the contactId field (Or contact as it appears on the filed list), it always changes back. Say if it originally is of contact A, if I change it into B, after clicking save button, it always changes back into A.

In order to investigate into this issue, I have disabled all the triggers for case object (Yes, it does have multiple triggers). And the issue still persists. And I have looked at the debug log, for all five workflow rules, the WF_CRITERIA is false in the debug log. And there is no flow for this case object. In the debug, no other trigger is running as well. And I don't see anything about this auto-change in the debug log.

I am quite confused here. What is happening behind this? How can I happen if it is not trigger, workflow or a flow?

The log's gist location is: https://gist.github.com/Lanceshi2/465ff2300ac77270b5d672628343eae7

Comment: Is the debug log < 2MB? If so do a search for DML_START (I think that is right might try DML_). If not, it could be truncated. Any Process Builder operating on case? Something is modifying it. I do not think escalation rules update other fields do they? Managed packages?

Comment: @Eric Thank you for the response. The debug log is much smaller than 2mb, it is only 22k. And I searched for DML but there is nothing.

Comment: @Eric I don't quite mind sharing it. I have generated a gist for it: https://gist.github.com/Lanceshi2/465ff2300ac77270b5d672628343eae7

Comment: @Eric I have updated the gist but I really don't believe much has changed. The debug level can only set to be fine and WF to be finer at the best.

Comment: Interesting.....How are you changing the field? UI, Code, Dataloader. Seems like the after update is covered and may not be the cause, time to look at the before

Comment: @Eric I have disabled all the triggers before trying this. I have tried in UI and developer console's query place. So I don't quite see anything related to UI side of thing - or dataloader.

Comment: I'll be watching this but for now thats all i have unfortunately sorry.

Comment: @Eric Thank you for the help. I am also thinking about what kind of sorcery is happening behind...

Comment: Just a quick suggestion, try to execute a code snippet to update the case contact from Dev console, see if it still happens? It will help to determine, if it's a UI thingy or server side.

Comment: @Salesforcesmarty Thanks for that. I have tried and it is definitely server side.

Comment: Any managed packages?

Comment: @AdrianLarson I think there are many. But even in that case, the triggers should still appear under the object section?